# Ubuntu trying to get Cambria font working with texLive and dealing with dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, latex, dpkg

I'm trying to run `sudo apt-get install -y texlive-fonts-extra` to get the Cambria font to work for a LaTeX project.  I have the fonts already downloaded and it works on a different computer to compile the document.  However, when I try to repeat the same process on a different computer, I am getting the following error and I am a loss of words on what to do.

When I try to compile the document, I am getting in a never-ending loop regarding the Cambria font.  To try and overcome this I tried the following.

Here is the error message I am getting trying this approach:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
texlive-fonts-extra is already the newest version (2019.202000218-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/144 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package liblsan0:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc-9-dev:amd64:
 libgcc-9-dev:amd64 depends on liblsan0 (>= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04); however:
  Package liblsan0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc-9-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-9:
 gcc-9 depends on libgcc-9-dev (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04); however:
  Package libgcc-9-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                       No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                         dpkg: error processing package gcc-9 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc:
 gcc depends on gcc-9 (>= 9.3.0-3~); however:
  Package gcc-9 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 liblsan0:amd64
 libgcc-9-dev:amd64
 gcc-9
 gcc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have a makefile that calls Tex which works perfectly, except for the text which was written in the Cambria font.

I tried following the same steps on a different computer but am just not sure.

Comment: Did you already try the advice in the error message `dpkg: error processing package liblsan0:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration`

Comment: I'm not sure how to reinstall dpkg.  Would you by chance know how to do that?

Comment: you should try to reinstall `liblsan0:amd64`